# What software pattern is one where I simply assemble things, such as create an array of certain type of data?

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented-design, mvc, naming

TL;DR: what do I call a section of code that is used to assemble a `Graph` object?

I have a fairly large section of code that is duplicated in a few areas.  I wish to extract it into its own class.  What do I call this class is my question.

The section contains code like this:

```
    /*
     * First Graph
     */
    $flow_curve = new CurveEntity();
    $curves = array();
    $curves[] = $flow_curve;
    $curves[] = new CurveEntity();
    $curves[] = new CurveEntity();

    $graphs = array();
    $graphs[] = new GraphEntity('graph_1');

    /*
     * Second Graph
     */
    $flow_curve = new CurveEntity($x);
    $curves = array();
    $curves[] = $flow_curve;
    $curves[] = new CurveEntity($y);
    $curves[] = new CurveEntity($z);

    $graphs = array();
    $graphs[] = new GraphEntity('graph_2');
```

This is not a controller and not view.  Is it part of the model?  Is it a service?  Is it a repository?  Nothing seems to fit.

Thinking about what this code represents, it looks like assembly of the $graph object, where the object is later used in the view for graph plotting.

Comment: The code you show has the pattern called "creating and filling arrays". It's not doing anything else.

Comment: alright.  I will create a class `CreateGraph` and refactor it later if need be.  I am thinking it is a glorified *value object* of sorts

Comment: a new pattern name is born...

Comment: Is `$curves` used in `$graphs` at some point? Right now it's not obvious how they are related, if at all.

Comment: I think this pattern is called "a snippet of mundane code". Seriously, though... Usually a "pattern" is defined as something like "[a general, reusable solution to a commonly occurring problem within a given context](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern)". What problem is your code trying to solve? In what context? What is your general solution? I don't see anything particularly distinctive in your code that would lend itself to being called a "pattern".

Comment: It is not a singleton pattern, since this object is created once, used once, and then discarted when its scope is done. `$curves` is used in `$graphs`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the variables `$flow_curve`, `$curves`, and `$graphs` belong to a bigger "something", give that "something" a name and create a class from it (maybe it is the `Graph` class you mentioned? Or maybe some `GraphCollection`?). Find an abstraction which suits your needs best. Then the code could be naturally placed in the **constructor** of that class - and that is the name of the "pattern" you are looking for, if you insist to call it a pattern (personally, I would not).

If, however, the assembling procedure is quite complex, and those variables are just temporary helpers, taking the code out of the constructor into a separate class is the classic [Builder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) design pattern, and the class where the code "lives" may be called `GraphBuilder` or `GraphCollectionBuilder`, or similar.